# Shell script running Python code from within conda env using macOS Automator

Tags: python, macos, shell, anaconda, automator

How can I run a shell script from within a `conda env` using `macOS Automator`? Normally I would do:

```
source activate my_conda_env
python script.py
```

But the above does not work in `Automator`. The error I receive is regarding missing modules (those only installed in `my_conda_env`), which indicates that the script is not started from `my_conda_env`.

Comment: The **Run Shell Script** action doesn't read any of the configuration files that an interactive shell running in Terminal would - are _all_ the environments getting set up with `activate`?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand, there is only one environment that I use, which is a conda environment.

Comment: Whatever environment(s) you have set up (for running in Terminal, etc) do not exist in the **Run Shell Script** action, so you need to set up what you need in the shell.  I don't have Anaconda to see what `source` is setting up, but you would need to set up the Anaconda (and possibly Python) environments (PATH, etc).

Comment: You should check my answer

Answer (score 3):

This is what you'll need

```
/Users/UserFolder/anaconda/envs/env-name/bin/python3 script.py
```

If you don't find anaconda under your UserFolder.
You'll have to find it,

- Activate your Conda environment
- Use this `which python`, to find the address of your python.
- copy that
- paste it before the script file

  ```
  /Copied/Address/ script.py
  ```

This will use the packages from the specified conda environment.

[image]